# How to solve error in sql decode of annotation in django

Tags: python, django, database, mongodb, djongo

I am working on django framework with mangodb database.

CRUD operations are working fine but I am facing an issue on annotation query receiving error:

```
djongo.sql2mongo.SQLDecodeError: FAILED SQL: SELECT "app_message"."type", SUM(CASE WHEN "app_message"."type" = %(0)s THEN %(1)s ELSE %(2)s END) AS "bot" FROM "app_message" GROUP BY "app_message"."type"  LIMIT 21
Params: ('Outbound', 1, 0)
Version: 1.2.38
```

```
Message.objects.values('type').\
            annotate(bot=Count(Case(When(type="Outbound", then='id'), default=Value(0),
                                    output_field=IntegerField()),
                               ))
```

Tried version 1.2.31 as well but no luck.

Python version: 3.6.1, 
Django version: 2.2.7

Comment: Please share the annotated query. [edit] the question.

Answer (score 0):

Counting that way makes no sense, since a `Value(0)` will be counted as one as well. Furthermore you do not need to filter yourself, Django has means to do filtering in an aggregate function, by using the [**`filter=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate-filter):

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

Message.objects.values('type').annotate(
    bot=Count('id', filter=Q(type='Outbound'))
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But this query is showing same error.

Comment: @raza: Then I guess it is the sql to mongo "converter" that here does not know what to do.

Comment: Message.objects.values('type').annotate(
            bot=Count('id'))
This part of the query is working fine but adding filter is creating problem

Answer (score 0):

This is you can do:

```
from django.db.models import Q, Sum, IntegerField

Message.objects.values('type').annotate(
     bot=Sum(Case(When(type="Outbound", then=1), 
     default=0,output_field=IntegerField()))
)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the comment but no luck unfortunately!